# Does order matter in email header?

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, rfc5322

I am using smtplib to create a MIMEMultipart email and the result is a header that looks as follows.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; charset="utf-8"; boundary="===============2613033831060434871=="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Subject: Your report is ready
From: no-reply@example.com
To: someone@example.com
```

Is this a valid e-mail header? Have experienced no complaints except for one person who is experiencing their e-mail being cut off before showing the body of the e-mail. They claim that it's because the Content-Type is appearing in the wrong place.

This is how the message was created

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from cl.library.htmlutils import html_to_text

def make_multipart_email(from_addr, to_addr, html, subject=None, text=None):
    text = text or html_to_text(html)
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.set_charset('utf8')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_addr
    msg['To'] = to_addr

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain', 'UTF-8'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'UTF-8'))

    return msg
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6)

> ... header fields are not guaranteed to be in a particular order.

So your email is valid.

Answer (score 0):

No, your email is not valid. It is missing the required `Date:` header.

The reference to this is in the very same reference provided by @snakecharmerb, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html#section-3.6